# Do I have to use the support library in Xamarin.Android to implement a toolbar?

Tags: xamarin.android

I would like to implement a toolbar in my app, but I don't necessarily want to support versions of android that are older than Oreo.

I have a toolbar, it shows up, it replaced the action bar, but I don't know how to make it act like an action bar and place buttons on it properly.

This is the xml of the activity I'd want the toolbar for:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">

    <Toolbar
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:title="Lyrics"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:titleTextColor="#DDDDDD"
        android:background="#112244"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:id="@+id/lyricsToolbar">

    </Toolbar>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:minHeight="30px"
        android:id="@+id/lyricsListView"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And this is in the .cs file:

```
var lyricsToolbar = FindViewById<Toolbar>(Resource.Id.lyricsToolbar);
SetActionBar(lyricsToolbar);
```

The toolbar does appear, but I don't know how to properly put buttons on it. All the tutorials and code I've found are putting a menu on an appcompat support library version. I'd like to add an "add lyrics" button to the toolbar on it's right side and nothing else (it would be just a plus sign and if you click it it opens up another activity where adding new lyrics is possible).

Is this a wrong approach?
How should I do this? Should I make the app more backward-compatible, otherwise I can't properly use toolbars?

Any help is appreciated,
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to achieve it like following GIF?

[image]

If so, you could add this plus icon directly like following layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 

>

 <Toolbar
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:title="Lyrics"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:titleTextColor="#DDDDDD"
    android:background="#112244"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:id="@+id/lyricsToolbar">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:id="@+id/Toolbar_add"
    />


</Toolbar>

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:minHeight="30px"
    android:id="@+id/lyricsListView"/>

 </LinearLayout >
```

And set the click event listener.

```
    [Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = true)]
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);


        var imageView =FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.Toolbar_add);
        imageView.Click += ImageView_Click;

    }

    private void ImageView_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        var intent=new Intent(this, typeof(LyricsActivity));
        StartActivity(intent);
    }
```

If you want to hide the action bar, please do not forget to add the `<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>` in `styles.xml` like following code.

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: yes, thank you

do you have some kind of social media or maybe an email I could write to to ask you some basic questions when I encounter problems such as this one?

Comment: Due to the policy, we cannot share any social media account or email in any threads, if you have any questions, you could open threads in stackoverflow, every community members will be happy to help you. If answer is helpful, please do not forget to mark it, it will help others who have simialr issue.

Comment: @rayaqin Are there any updates for this issue? If the reply is helpful, please try to mark it as an answer,  it will help others who have similar issue.